# Strange white line inside layer-list

Tags: android, android-layout

For the background of a button we want to have a double gradient. Therefore we use a layer-list with two shapes inside, each for each gradient part. The selector looks like this.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:bottom="24dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <gradient android:startColor="#9ccb37" android:endColor="#64bb3a" android:angle="270" />
          <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
                   android:topRightRadius="6dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:top="24dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <gradient android:startColor="#45ac42" android:endColor="#029345" android:angle="270" />
          <corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp" android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                   android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

The result is exactly what we want and looks like this.

[image: correct button]

Amongst our testing devices is an [HTC Desire HD](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_hd-3468.php) and it has an annoying white line straight through the button. On all other devices (both with lower and higher dpi's) the result is ok. On this device however, the result looks like this:

[image: strange button]

It's a completely mystery to me why it would render like this on this device only. All pointers welcome!

Comment: Maybe worthwhile to look at the margin and padding values of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Do you have to have a clear distinction in the gradient or can you do a transitional gradient like this

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#2f6699" android:startColor="#449def" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2f6699" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```